# Entity Framework connection factory not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection, entity-framework-6, sqlanywhere

I use entity framework 6 and try to overwrite the connection string factory.

I've written the following connection factory:

```
internal class MyDBConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public System.Data.Common.DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        SAConnection connection = new SAConnection(ConnectionManager.GetConnectionString(nameOrConnectionString ?? "Default"));

        return connection;
    }
}
```

Than i have written my own configuration class:

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        // Set provider
        SetProvider();

        // Connection-Information
        SetConnectionInformation();
    }

    private void SetProvider()
    {
        DbProviderServices provider = new iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAProviderServices();

        this.SetProviderServices("iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere", provider);
    }

    private void SetConnectionInformation()
    {
        this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new MyDBConnectionFactory());
    }
}
```

Finally i have added the configuration to the db-context:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{

}
```

My problem is, that `CreateConnection` in `MyDBConnectionFactory` will never be called and i get the following error message: **The underlying provider failed on Open.**

Why does my connection will never be created?

Maybe some one has a solution, that would be perfect, thank you.

Comment: I am getting this error. Can you help me in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083763/multiple-sybase-dlls-are-loaded-when-using-entity-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important that the configuration section in the app.config does not exists, because it has a higher priority.

Comment: which configuration section please?